# How to simulate a SEM Model with Simsem in R

Tags: r, simulation, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

I would like to simulate a structural equation model in R and fixing the mean and standard deviation for each variable. I attempted to perform a simulation in Onyx, but I can't fix this parameters

My model should include:

Three endogenous variables
Four latent variables
Eight exogenous variables (two for each latent variable)

Do you have any advice?